# Elastic score query

Tags: elasticsearch

I need help with an elastic request, the story is as follows:
I have a table that looks like -

`{ "name" : "Laptop Lenovo", "description" : "laptop", "coord" : { "lat" : 55.00, "lon" : 60.00 } }`

I need a query that will give me all the documents whose name and description most closely match the query, and whose coordinates are closest to the query.

the highest priority in the name and description, in the second plan coordinates.
Now i'm stuck with this but it doesn't work:

```html
{
  "filter": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "brand_product": [
          false
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": "geoData",
        "query": {
          "function_score": {
            "boost_mode": "sum",
            "score_mode": "multiply",
            "functions": [
              {
                "linear": {
                  "geoData.lat": {
                    "offset": "?1",
                    "origin": 100,
                    "scale": 10
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "exp": {
                  "geoData.lon": {
                    "offset": "?2",
                    "origin": 226,
                    "scale": 4
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you read about [geo queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-queries.html)?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @Paulo at the moment Score, but so far it is not working well, since elastic is a relatively new technology for me, I have a weak understanding of the construction

Comment: What I ment is, show us what you have done, where you are failing (show some details in the question, provide the query) Stackoverflow is not a do my code for free platform ^^, it is to help with bugs, precise question.